# Set an onChange for checkbox in React?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, onchange

I'm trying to update a record by selecting a checkbox when a book has been read. Whenever I refresh the page, the checkbox returns as unchecked. How can I store the selected checkbox and see it checked after the page is refreshed?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Book = ( {title, author, id, getBooks}) => {
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    await axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books/${id}`, {
        book: {
          [name]: value,
          finished: !finished
        },
      })
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          defaultValue={title}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="form-control"
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="author"
          defaultValue={author}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="form-control"
        />
      </td>
      <td className="text-center">
        <div className="form-check form-check-inline pt-2">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="finished"
            defaultChecked={finished}
            className="form-check-input"
            onChange={() => setFinished(!finished)}
          />
          <label className="form-check-label">
            Done
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
}

export default Book
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: You probably want to use `value={title}` instead of `defaultValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at this component, I assume you are fetching the list of Books from the parent and I also assume that you have `finished` property from the book list data that you've fetch as well. You can pass that `finished` property to this component and set it as initial value to your `finished` state.

Sample on you do it

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Book = ( {title, author, id, finished, getBooks}) => {
  const [isFinished, setIsFinished] = useState(finished)

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    await axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books/${id}`, {
        book: {
          [name]: value,
          finished: !isFinished
        },
      })
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          defaultValue={title}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="form-control"
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="author"
          defaultValue={author}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="form-control"
        />
      </td>
      <td className="text-center">
        <div className="form-check form-check-inline pt-2">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="finished"
            defaultChecked={isFinished}
            className="form-check-input"
            onChange={() => setIsFinished(!isFinished)}
          />
          <label className="form-check-label">
            Done
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
}

export default Book
```

### **Additional notes:**

I changed your state name into `isFinished` to avoid same name error with your new props.

Also, if you want to be sure to save the checkbox change during checking/unchecking, you also need to listen to the changes on `isFinished` state using `useEffect` and save it again using your axios call.

Honestly tho, what you have right now is a very bad design. Don't spam api calls every change on your input. Use debounce or something. Just dont api call every change.